# Objects in PHP: More or Less is better?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, object

I have asked aqbout timezones and date/time before but this is a more specific question, more about Objects in PHP.

```
<?PHP
//set the user's time zone on page load
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");

//convert the timestamp from DB into the user's time
$timestamp = '2008-05-01 13:44:19'; //this would normally be returned from mysql
echo ConvertDateTime($timestamp, "America/Los_Angeles");

//here is the function to convert it
function ConvertDateTime($timeString, $timeZone)
{
    if ( $d = new DateTime($timeString) ) {
        $d-&gt;setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($timeZone));
        return $d-&gt;format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }
    return null;
}
?>
```

Ok this is probably a dumb queston to some but I really do not know a lot or have much experience when it comes to classes and objects, generally on a page for example I will create 1 database object and run every mysql query on the page with that 1 object set.  I always think less objects is probably better but I have read on this site that having hundreds of objects would be the same speed and resourses used compared to 1 object, not sure f it's true or not.

My question, in the function above, you can see that a new DateTime object is created everytime the function is called, could be 100 times on some pages in my situation.  So should I use like a singlton or even I could set a dattim object 1 time in the header where my database object is set as well or should I just let the function create a ton of object?

Please explain the pros and cons and which I should probably do, appreciate any advice, some may say I am pre-optimizing, well I have been optimizing a current site for over 2 years to get it where I wanted it and now I am re-building that SAME site so I kinda know what userload to expect and stuff and I would rather fix something like this now instead of later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should I use like a singlton

Singleton are not without problems -- for instance, they often make (automated) testing difficult. Which is one of the reasons for which they are less and liked by "big" Frameworks *(I'm thinking about Zend Framework and Symfony, which are reducing the number of Singletons for their next major version)*

> I could set a dattim object 1 time in
>   the header

Using a global variable / object can go with side-effects, too ; If a variable is meant as "local", it should be local -- code readibily and ability to understand it are generally more important than a fraction of a millisecond.

For extreme and specific cases, the only *(true)* solution is to profile : you want your script / application to go faster ? To use less CPU ?

Then, first of all, profile it ! It'll help identify bottlenecks -- and show you on what you should concentrate.

Chances are you have plenty of things that could be optimized fastest *(i.e. which would take less time to think about, code, and test)* -- and would get you higher performance gains.

In the end, you always have to choose between :

- the best possible performances
- time it takes to develop / optimize something
- time it takes to maintain it ; including for someone else than you.

And, quite often, a new, more powerful server (or a second one) will finally coest less than a couple of weeks spent optimizing to get only 5% !

*(Note I didn't say you shouldn't optimize ; but you shouldn't over-optimize.)*

Comment: besides doing test and stuff, I guess I am trying to find out is it bad to only use 1 object?  I see people using a ton of objects sometimes and I don't see a reason, I am new to objects though so there might be a reason and I just don't know what it is yet?

Comment: @jasondavis : if it makes more sense to use several objects than it makes using only 1, then using only one object is "bad" : what generally matters is that your code makes sense. ;; you generally really don't need to over-optimize your code : your time is more important (and costs more, when you're being paid) than 1 or 2 percents of CPU you might (or not) gain with that kind of optimization. ;; Gaining 25% of CPU in 2 days is great (an "easy" idea that often works being "cache") ;; Gaining 1 ms in 10 days is often not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

> I always think less objects is
>   probably better but I have read on
>   this site that having hundreds of
>   objects would be the same speed and
>   resourses used compared to 1 object,
>   not sure f it's true or not.

Additional objects require additional memory space - so you can assume that path of action will have repercussion (however, they may not be noticeable/require action on your part).

> you can see that a new DateTime object is created everytime the
>   function is called, could be 100 times
>   on some pages in my situation. So
>   should I use like a singlton

Yes, you could use a singleton - Or cache the result for the page (Are you displaying multiple different times on the same page - or just the same computed time in many places?)

Comment: Hi it is different times and caching would be nearly impossible or not worth it as it is a large social networing site, there would be thousands of caches for do that, there could actually be millions of pages

Answer (score 0):

In this case creating a new object each time the function is called will not give that much extra memory usage: each time the function is left, the memory is freed.

If you are calling the function a lot of times with exactly the same $timeString and $timeZone, you might want to add caching of the result. If most of the calls will be unique, I wouldn't add caching: it might help you performance in speed, but storing all results, while not reusing them is a waste of memory.

Comment: Yes it would be different times, I pretty much trieing to find out in my example if I should do 1 object or 100 objects for 100 different times on a page

Comment: If both the timestamp and the timezone could change on each call you'll need to do it for each sorry to say. If one of them is constant then it's a smaller domain space and could be other options and since I said something about it understand you actually possible results only number 86400 for the time part which could be handled with a lookup using an offset between the timezones. Might try looking at the problem a different way and it'll solve itself.